# If you have a ball-and-socket hitch, you will also need to attach safety chains between the trailer and the towing vehicle

Tags: trailer-hitch

How come the following requirement doesn't apply to fifth-wheel trailers? Thank you!

"[If you have a ball-and-socket hitch, you will also need to attach safety chains between the trailer and the towing vehicle. Chains should be crossed under the tongue of the trailer and fastened securely. This applies to all trailers except fifth-wheel trailers.](https://www.alberta.ca/equipment-trailers.aspx)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Gooseneck/5th wheel trailer connections use what is called a "positive lock" mechanism. It works the same for big-rigs (semi-trailers) as they use the same. The positive lock does not allow for decoupling unless the lock is pulled. If a 5th wheel connection is not properly locked, it will slide back out immediately upon trying to pull the trailer. There are a multitude of reasons why regular ball-and-socket type connections require chains, the majority of them is user stupidity (yes, we all make mistakes). [Here is a web page](https://www.etrailer.com/question-66117.html) from a company which states pretty much the same.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed answer!